# Sharepoint 2007 - Custom webpart deployment doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I have a custom webpart for Sharepoint 2007. I am trying to deploy it to a new Sharepoint web application. I am using WSPBuilder with VS2010 to do the deploy. When I examine the wss\VirtualDirectories\ folder for the web app, the wpcatalog folder does not exist there. When I go to the Web Part Gallery and click "New" button, the web part is no there either. What could be causing this behavior? Are there any other ways to troubleshoot it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the wpcatalog is actually a document library containing the .webpart definition files. It is stored in the content database, not the file system.

You need to verify the solution is in fact deployed to your web application, and then activate any features if necessary. You can verify the solution deployment under central administration\operations\solution management.

Comment: +1 verifying the solution was deployed successfully is definitely the first place to look. If it was deployed successfully, you can try importing the .webpart file directly onto your page if it doesn't show up in the Web Part gallery.

Comment: I hope I didnt accidentally flag your response. iPad + fat finger